# Computation of fundamental group of the Möbius strip

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

How would one go about computing the fundamental group of the Möbius strip using its polygon representation?

Comment: I would deformation retract the M\"obius strip to the center circle and then compute it for the circle.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the fastest way to solve this is to note that the Mobius strip is homotopy-equivalent to the circle, which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$. Intuitively, draw a line in the middle of the Mobius strip that makes a complete circle around it. Then you map the strip onto the central circle - this is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: I meant using the method that is used in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6f3I-RiWbk&list=PL6763F57A61FE6FE8&index=26&ab_channel=InsightsintoMathematics  maybe my english terminology is a bit poor